# PDO: select rows when date greater then now or less then now in single query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to select rows when date column is: 1) only greater then now, 2) only less then now, 3) any, in single query based on single variable.

```
$finished = false (1) / true (2) / null (3);

if ($finished === false) { // Greater then now
    $date = $now;
} else if ($finished === null) { // Any date
    $date = '1970-01-01 00:00:00';
} else if ($finished === true) { // Less then now
    ???
}

SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > :date
```

How can I modify query to select date *less then now* as well? I tried to put *greater then sign (>)* into $date variable, but PDO returns error. Is it possible to do it in single query at all?

Sorry for english.

**UPDATE**

Single query, single variable. If I want search just for finished rows set $finished = true. Search just for non finished rows set $finished = false etc. Here's my working example:

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

if ($finished === null) { // Search for any rows.
    $after = $now;
    $before = $now;
} else if ($finished === true) { // Search for finished rows (date <= now).
    $after = null;
    $before = $now;
} else if ($finished === false) { // Search for not finished rows (date > now).
    $after = $now;
    $before = null;
}

$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE (date > :after OR date <= :before)");

$query->execute(array(
    ':after' => $after,
    ':before' => $before
));
```

Comment: Why not use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and why only a single query?

Comment: You can write `WHERE date > '$date' OR date < '$date'` for a non-PDO query to get the data you seek.

Comment: How could `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` help? I would like single query because in fact is much more complex and I don't want to duplicate it just for this.

Comment: @Dreamwalker: But that would return only any rows except now, wouldn't it?

Comment: @hovado:  Are you wanting to apply a data filter at the server level during the search?  You want to join three separate searches, if all three are empty you would have no matching results.

Comment: @Dreamwalker: No, I decide it before search. Want search for rows with date > now => set $finished = false, less then now => $finished = true etc.

Comment: I don't think you have enough code here to answer your question.  sorry

Comment: It looks like you might need to conditionally compose your query string rather than have one query string you use all the time.

Comment: @tadman: I'm quite newbie in PDO. Why is it better? Thanks.

Comment: As @tadman suggests - write your statement to your conditions and prepare it.  So instead of `$before` and `$after` just simply use `$statement = 'SELECT ...'`

Comment: @Ash: Actually I would like avoid that, because my statement is quite long and has a lot more params. Is my solution so bad?

Comment: It's usually not a big deal to conditionally add components to an array, then join them with `implode` at the end.

Comment: You were right. Compose query separately before preparing is really better and offer more options.